# Sort pandas DataFrame by linear combination of two columns without creating new column

Tags: python, pandas

Is there an easy way to sort a DataFrame based on a linear combination of two columns  without creating a new column for that value? Given

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[4,1],[2,3]], columns=list('AB'))
```

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

I would want to sort `df` by a given linear combination of columns `A` and `B` (e.g. `A*B`). Calling `sort_values` with a key function does not work, because it applies the function to each column individually.
Ideally, I would do something like:

```
df.sort_values(by=['A','B'], key=lambda a,b: a*b) # does not work
```

Right now I am creating an extra column `sort` like this and I am wondering whether that is necessary.

```
df['sort'] = df['A']*df['B']
df.sort_values(['sort'])
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) with multiplied `Series` and `.get`:

```
df1 = df.sort_index(key=(df.A*df.B).get)
```

Or [`Series.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html) with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df1 = df.iloc[(df.A*df.B).argsort()]
```